# How to distinguish between "each" and "every"?

Tags: determiners

A.  She gave an apple to every of the children.

B.  She gave an apple to each of the children.

Would you please show me which one is correct? or if they both could be considered correct?

Answer (score 5):

The word "every" is a determiner, whereas the word "each" is both a determiner and a pronoun.

So, when these words are used as a determiner, you can say:

> She gave an apple to every child.
>
> She gave an apple to each child.

As you can use "each" as a pronoun, you can say:

> She gave an apple to each of the children.

On the other hand, every isn't a pronoun, so you cannot say "......every of the children".

Comment: You could say 'She gave an apple to every one of the children.'

Comment: ssav, You are right.

Answer (score 1):

B is the correct one.  'Every' is a determiner that needs a *singular* noun with *no preposition*, here: "every child".

Comment: What about "every 2 weeks" vs "each 2 weeks". Personally, i think every 2 weeks is more sensible however 2 weeks is not singular

Comment: Yes, every [so many] is a special case in which the "so many of something" is used as a singular - an item in a series, and has nothing to do with the question asked.  You can't say "each two weeks" BTW.